# Обновление данных в новости (activerecord)

Tags: php, orm, activerecord

Имеется метод, который выводит одну новость:

```
    public function actionOne()
{
    $id_article = $_GET['id'];
    $onenews = NewsModel::getOne($id_article);
    $view = new View();
    $view->listonenews = $onenews;
    $view->display('adminnews/one.php');

// Здесь происходит обновление записей, данные приходят из формы

    $onenews->title = $_POST['title'];
    $onenews->date = $_POST['date'];
    $onenews->text = $_POST['text'];
    $onenews->updateNews();
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что форму обрабатывает эта же страница, а следовательно, на экран выводятся предупреждения, поскольку данные из формы еще не пришли:

> Notice: Undefined index: title

и так со всеми полями, которые я собираются обновить.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить этот момент.

Comment: ну проверьте через isset или empty перед использованием $_POST['title'] и прочего, а причем здесь все эти теги про pdo/orm/ar?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамотно разделить обработку и рендер формы на разные action в одном вы будете рендерить форму как есть, в другом обрабатывать форму. И стоит использовать методы работы с пост на подобие `getPost(),getParam()`  и т.д. и т.п. используемого фреймворка, или же написать свой метод

```
public function getPost($key) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

и обработка формы будет выглядить примерно так

```
public function actionOneSave() {
       $onenews->title = $this->getPost('title');
       $onenews->date = $this->getPost('date');
       $onenews->text = $this->getPost('text');
       $onenews->updateNews();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет!